# Nothing shows when fetching data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm making a simple like/dislike system at the bottom of my angular web app. I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON file, but nothing shows up (as you see in the bottom [here](https://ad667068912adccb975eee14116cefd5fb123f74.googledrive.com/host/0B_tg4it67g1bWWFHV3hnaXVEcGs/)). The relevant part of the code is as under:

**index.html**

```html
<div class="content" id="sub-section">
      <div class="text-area">
          <div class="text" style="color:#3A3A3A">
              Dersom du likte eller ikke likte appen kan du rate den under.<br>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div>
          <table style="text-align:center; font-size:1em" class="table-responsive table" ng-controller="rateCtrl">
              <tr>
                  <td>Jeg likte den!</td>
                  <td>Jeg likte den ikke!</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><p class="likes" ng-click="addLike()">+{{likes}}</p></td>
                  <td><p class="dislikes" ng-click="addDislike()">-{{dislikes}}</p></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**app.js**

```js
.controller('rateCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('rating.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.likes = data.likes;
          $scope.dislikes = data.dislikes;
          $scope.addLike = function () {
              $scope.likes = $scope.likes + 1;
          };
          $scope.addDislike = function () {
              $scope.dislikes = $scope.dislikes + 1;
          };
      });
  });
```

**rating.json**

```js
{
   "likes": 12,
   "dislikes": 0
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly parsing data from your response. You should do it like this:

```
$scope.likes = data[0].likes;
$scope.dislikes = data[1].dislikes;
```

Because your `rating.json` actually contains array with two objects.

But I don't think that it's good practice to store data in that way. If you have an opportunity to change structure of your json, it will be much better (with this structure your code should works correctly):

```
{
   "likes": 12,
   "dislikes": 0
}
```

And you don't need to add `rating.` prefix to your variables and functions because they are defined at the `$scope`.

```
<tr>
   <td><p class="likes" ng-click="addLike()">+{{likes}}</p></td>
   <td><p class="dislikes" ng-click="addDislike()">-{{dislikes}}</p></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I forgot that. Thought it was an object. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: tjespe has it in his site the way you have suggested and it works there. (at least it passes the point this question is about)

Comment: Thanks, I think I've followed all your instructions now. Finally it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I separated the function because they don't make sense. I also changed the json format because they shouldn't be an array especially likes and dislike will always be like that unless your json data is per user basis. That's when I'll use array. For now, it's a simple object.

Also, I noticed you are using controllerAs. That's a good thing because now we can delete the evil $scope. You'll notice that I didn't use $scope anymore. :) And the reason why your code is also not working is because you are using controllerAs with $scope to pull it. That won't work.

```
app.controller('rateCtrl', function($http) {
   this.ratingData = {};

   this.addLike = function () {
      this.ratingData.likes = this.ratingData.likes + 1;
      console.log('add like', this.ratingData.likes);
    };
    this.addDislike = function () {
      this.ratingData.dislikes = this.ratingData.dislikes + 1;
      console.log('add disklike', this.ratingData.dislikes);
    };

    $http.get('rating.json').success(function(data) {
      console.log('this', this);
      this.ratingData = data;
      console.log(this.ratingData);
    }.bind(this));
});
```

and here is a live running code that you wanted to accomplish. You can play with it - http://plnkr.co/edit/aWB5ym0p3Sgtqv9Mxs0r?p=preview

Comment: Here is a very good information about what bind is and what it does with examples - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

Your app is not referencing the properties in rating.json correctly. If reformatting the JSON as suggested by lcycool and charlietfl does not work, it is likely a reference error, and you should consider either specifying the full path of the file or placing it in the same folder as app.js

I believe I found the issue. {{ rating.likes }} references $scope.rating.likes, which is undefined. Change this to {{ likes }} (ref: $scope.likes) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format doesn't match with the way you are trying to access it through JS object. This is how you resolve a problem like this.

Put a break point at this line:

```
$scope.likes = data.likes;
```

Go to console and type `data`

Now you will see the structure of your `data` object. Explore it and change your code (or JSON) the way it matches with each other.